# Ubuntu Studio, no sound on any device

Tags: sound, usb, soundcard, ubuntu-studio

It's been two days I have tried to make this work. I have 3 sound output : regular audio jack from my soundcard, USB MOTU soundcard, USB Logitech speakers. The latter two seem not to be detected at all. The first seems to be detected but still no sound. I have uninstalled and reinstalled PulseAudio and AlsaMixer according to some tip on a blog but it did not work either. All the above work like a charm on Windows 7 and Windows 8.

I'm really trying to give Ubuntu a try but it's starting not to be such a great experience when I can't get something this simple to work after two days :|

And yes I have double (triple) checked that the volume on all devices is not turned off and that no mute setting is on (including auto-mute in alsamixer).

Does anyone have a clue what could be wrong ?

Thanks

(Also, please assume I have no knowledge **at all** of Ubuntu since it's pretty much the case)

Edit: Here is the output of "sudo aplay -l"

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC889 Analog [ALC889 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 1: ALC889 Digital [ALC889 Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 7: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 8: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 9: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

My primary sound card (i.e. not the external MOTU one) comes from my motherboard, it's a Gigabyte Z68 HD (or something like that, will try to find the exact model).

Comment: What soundcard do you have?

Comment: @UriHerrera added the result of sudo aplay -l

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not have single clue why but here is what fixed my problem (completely by mistake):

Using pavucontrol I have disabled "GF110 High Definition Controller" and the sound will only work if "Built-in audio" is set to anything *Analog*. It will not work if the setting is digital. Can anyone comment on why that would happen ?

Thanks.